# CastCompanion Lock and Notification controls dont work

Tags: android, google-cast

Hi i have added the CCL in my project. The notification and lock screen get shown correctly. But the controls in the widgets don't do anything with the currently playing video on Chromecast

```
    videoCastManager.enableFeatures(VideoCastManager.FEATURE_NOTIFICATION |
            VideoCastManager.FEATURE_LOCKSCREEN | VideoCastManager.FEATURE_DEBUGGING);
```

i Have added the following in the manifest:

```
 <activity android:name="com.google.sample.castcompanionlibrary.cast.player.VideoCastControllerActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:label="@string/app_name" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:parentActivityName=".activity.HubActivity" android:theme="@style/NGSNTheme"> <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY" android:value=".activity.HubActivity" />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            </intent-filter> </activity>


        <service android:name="com.google.sample.castcompanionlibrary.notification.VideoCastNotificationService"
            android:exported="false"> <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.sample.castcompanionlibrary.action.toggleplayback" />
            <action android:name="com.google.sample.castcompanionlibrary.action.stop" />
            <action android:name="com.google.sample.castcompanionlibrary.action.notificationvisibility" />
        </intent-filter> </service>


        <receiver android:name="com.google.sample.castcompanionlibrary.remotecontrol.MediaIntentReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.media.AUDIO_BECOMING_NOISY" /> <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON" /> <action android:name="android.media.VOLUME_CHANGED_ACTION" /> <action
                android:name="com.google.sample.castcompanionlibrary.action.toggleplayback" /> <action android:name="com.google.sample.castcompanionlibrary.action.stop" />
            </intent-filter> </receiver>
```

Comment: What does your logs show? Also, why do you have two android:name attributes for the activity that you have shown?

Comment: Try to use VideoIntentReceiver instead of MediaIntentReceiver in the receiver tag. It works in my case.

Answer (score 1):

you need to replace the code you've shown with the following, in your manifest.

```
 <receiver android:name="com.google.android.libraries.cast.companionlibrary.remotecontrol.VideoIntentReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.media.AUDIO_BECOMING_NOISY" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.libraries.cast.companionlibrary.action.toggleplayback" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.libraries.cast.companionlibrary.action.stop" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service
        android:name="com.google.android.libraries.cast.companionlibrary.notification.VideoCastNotificationService"
        android:exported="false" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.libraries.cast.companionlibrary.action.toggleplayback" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.libraries.cast.companionlibrary.action.stop" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.libraries.cast.companionlibrary.action.notificationvisibility" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <service android:name="com.google.android.libraries.cast.companionlibrary.cast.reconnection.ReconnectionService"/>
```